# How to populate dropdown values according to mysql values

Tags: jquery, codeigniter

I have a form with three dropdowns. Value of 2nd dropdown populates according to 1st dropdown and value of third dropdown populates according to the 2nd dropdown

So I'm able to populate the dropdowns according to the values and insert them into the database.

Now my problem is how to preselect the dropdown values when I edit the form.

### Here is my form:

```
<form action="edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
    <label>Subject <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
    <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
        <option value="">Select Subject Name</option>
        <?php foreach($subjects as $sub):?>
        <option value="<?php echo $sub['id']?>"><?php echo 
ucwords($sub['subject_name']);?></option>
        <?php endforeach;?>
    </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label>Topic <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="topic" id="topic" required>

            <!-- using ajax to populate dropdown according to the 
selection of subject -->

        </select>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label>Co-Topic <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <select class="form-control" name="cotopic" id="cotopic" 
required>

            <!-- using ajax to populate dropdown according to the 
selection of subject -->

        </select>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

### jquery to populate:

```
<script>
$('#subject').on('change',function()
{
var subid=$(this).val();
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo site_url('AdminTopics/topicOnSubjects');?>",
    data:{subid:subid},
    success:function(res)
    {
        $("#topic").html(res);
        console.log(res);
    }
    }); 
});
</script>
<script>
$('#topic').on('change',function()
{
var tid=$(this).val(); 
$.ajax({
    type:"POST",
    url:"<?php echo site_url('AdminCoTopics/coTopicOnTopics');?>",
    data:{tid:tid},
    success:function(res)
    {
        $("#cotopic").html(res);
        console.log(res);
    }
    }); 

});
</script>
```

### controller

```
public function topicOnSubjects()
//this function is used in ajax on createCoTopic page to populate topic 
based on selection of subject
{
    $post=$this->input->post();
    $result=$this->tm->getTopicBySubjects($post);
    echo $result;
}

public function coTopicOnTopics()
//this function is used in ajax on createCoTopic page to populate topic 
based on selection of subject
{
    $post=$this->input->post();
    $result=$this->tm->getCoTopicByTopic($post);

    echo $result;
}
```

### Model:

```
public function getTopicBySubjects($post)
{
    $subid=$post['subid'];
    $q=$this->db
                ->select('id,topic_name')
                ->from('topics')
                ->where('sub_id',$subid)
                ->get();
    $row=$q->result();
    $result='<option value="">Select Topic</option>';
    foreach($row as $row)
    {
        $result .='<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.ucwords($row->topic_name).'</option>';
    }
    return $result;

}
public function getCoTopicByTopic($post)
{
    $tid=$post['tid'];
    $q=$this->db
                ->select('id,co_topic_name')
                ->from('cotopics')
                ->where('topic_id',$tid)
                ->get();
    $row=$q->result();
    $result='<option value="">Select Topic</option>';
    foreach($row as $row)
    {
        $result .='<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.ucwords($row->co_topic_name).'</option>';
    }
    return $result;

}
```

### I have tried like this but value of second dropdown is not populating

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
$('#subject').val("value from db").attr("selected","selected");

});
</script>
```

Comment: are you using the same form for add and edit or you have two separate forms for these?

Comment: I have 2 separate forms. The model and controller to populate the dropdown is same on add form and edit form @AlokMali

Comment: I have provided a solution, which I use. Please check it once.

Answer (score 0):

Populate the select tag also from your model

```
public function getTopicBySubjects($post)
{
    $subid=$post['subid'];
    $q=$this->db
                ->select('id,topic_name')
                ->from('topics')
                ->where('sub_id',$subid)
                ->get();
    $row=$q->result();
    $result='<select class="form-control" name="topic" id="topic" required><option value="">Select Topic</option>';
    foreach($row as $row)
    {
        $result .='<option value="'.$row->id.'">'.ucwords($row->topic_name).'</option>';
    }
    $result .='</select>';
    return $result;

}
```

HTML

```
<div class="col-md-4 form-group">
        <label>Co-Topic <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
        <div id="dynSel"></div>
        <!-- remove your select from here
           <select class="form-control" name="cotopic" id="cotopic" 
required>
         </select>-->

    </div>
```

In your **AJAX**

```
$("#dynSel").html(res)
```

Comment: do you see any error? or what is the issue you face?

Comment: no i didnt see any error in cosnole log. but if i change the value of 1st dropdown then it shows the 2nd dropdown. I want to preselect all values of three dropdowns as i am edititing the form

Comment: Try this `$("#subject").val('value from db');` to preselect

Comment: I have already tried it. This will select the value of 1st dropdown but value of 2nd dropdown is not selecting according to the preselect value of 1st dropddown

Comment: ok then try `$("#subject").val('value from db').trigger('change')`.

Answer (score 0):

@denny, You have to get topics/cotopics on edit also. But get only specific data.

Please refer this way...

**In Controller**

```
public function edit($itemId = ''){
  /** here you have the primary Id of item */
  /** Get item details by item id*/
  $data['itemDetails'] = $this->model->function($itemId);
  /** get all subjects */
  $data['subjects'] = $this->model->function();
  /** get all topics of selected subject */
  $data['topics'] = $this->model->function($data['itemDetails']['subject']);
  /** get all cotopics of selected topic */
  $data['cotopics'] = $this->model->function($data['itemDetails']['topic']);

  /** Send this data to view */
}
```

**In View**

```
<form action="edit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label>Subject <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="subject" id="subject" required>
                <option value="">Select Subject Name</option>
                <?php foreach ($subjects as $sub): ?>
                    <option <?php if($itemDetails['subject'] == $sub['id']){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $sub['id'] ?>"><?php echo
                ucwords($sub['subject_name']);
                    ?></option>
<?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label>Topic <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="topic" id="topic" required>
                <!-- using ajax to populate dropdown according to the 
    selection of subject -->
                <option value="">Select Topic</option>
                <?php foreach ($topics as $topic): ?>
                    <option <?php if($itemDetails['topic'] == $topic['id']){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $topic['id'] ?>"><?php echo
                ucwords($topic['topic_name']);
                    ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 form-group">
            <label>Co-Topic <span style="color:red;">*</span></label>
            <select class="form-control" name="cotopic" id="cotopic" 
                    required>
                <!-- using ajax to populate dropdown according to the 
    selection of subject -->
                <option value="">Select Cotopic</option>
                <?php foreach ($cotopics as $cotopic): ?>
                    <option <?php if($itemDetails['cotopic'] == $cotopic['id']){ echo 'selected'; } ?> value="<?php echo $cotopic['id'] ?>"><?php echo
                ucwords($cotopic['cotopic_name']);
                    ?></option>
                <?php endforeach; ?>
            </select>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>
```

And when you will change any of dropdown, it will work from your ajax call.
If you have any query, then let me know.